# How to get a specific value between other values having the same Key

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

My JSON response is like this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "285",
               "short_name" : "285",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
```

I need to get the last value for the Key `long_name`:

```
{
                   "long_name" : "Brooklyn",//i need to get this "Brooklyn"
                   "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
                   "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
                },
```

How can i get that although there is a lot of Values with the same key `long_name`:

```
NSArray *resultsArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"results"];//what to do next?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[[[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"address_components"] valueForKey:@"long_name"] lastObject];
```

Breaking down:

```
// get array of address components
[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"address_components"]

// calling this on array will get you long_name values from ALL elements
...] valueForKey:@"long_name"]

// finally grab the last element long_name array
...] lastObject];
```

Equivalent would be:

```
[[[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"address_components"] lastObject] valueForKey:@"long_name"];
```

Breaking down:

```
// get array of address components
[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"address_components"]

// get last dictionary
...] lastObject]

// get long_name from last dictionary
...] valueForKey:@"long_name"]
```

Comment: Would you please clarify your answer, also, that's not the last object, i have similar object after it but i didn't show them in my post, so shall i replace it by the order number?

Comment: Yes, replace `lastObject` call with `objectAtIndex:someIndex`.

Comment: @Malek: The second choice is much better as it does not involve creating an intermediate array, however semantically they produce the same result so either works as Eimantas states.

Comment: @Eimantas: when i try this:`location=[[[[[resultsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"address_components"] lastObject] valueForKey:@"long_name"]objectAtIndex:3];`i got an exception `[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Remove the call for `lastObject` right after `address_components`